# Trouble playing long .wav files in winsound

Tags: python, wav, winsound

I'm having trouble with some simple winsound code:

```
import winsound

winsound.PlaySound("song.wav", winsound.SND_FILENAME)
```

The problem is that whenever I try to play a .wav file, all I get is a Windows error sound and then the program continues onward.

I have a feeling that it may be because the file is too large seeing as I have done it before with shorter .wav files. Is there a size/length limit? Does anyone know the boundaries? If so, are there any ways of getting around this?

Comment: How large ist too large?

Comment: For all sizes I have it appears to work perfectly fine, this is 0 to 11MB. So I would need additional information on the size.

Comment: largest is @ 80mb and the smallest is @ 5mb.

Comment: You have any idea where I could get such a large .wav file?

Comment: you could make a noise file in audacity using generate.. or do what i did and download a mixtape off youtube using a youtube converter. (highest quality possible)

Answer (score 0):

I used to have this problem also, but when I put the audio file in the Python directory, it worked.
Try that.
:)